# In GitHub how do I automatically force a feature branch to be up to date with the main branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In GitHub there's a rule under the branch rule called `Require branches to be up to date before merging`. This is close to what I want but it doesn't automatically enforce the update until the user clicks on the button in the PR.

This is what I see when my feature branch is out of date from the Github UI
[image]
However I would like it so that this actually never shows up and instead automatically merges the latest changes from my main branch into my feature branch. I wanted to know if something like this was possible from the UI without using the command line

Comment: Yes that is the case. And your **specific** questions is? What did you try? What didn't work? Have you tried git ls-remote and could you spot the references for each PR that Github keeps up to date incl. for the preferred influx strategy? Could you spot the message on a PR whether it is up-to-date or has conflicts? How do you think Github knows?

Comment: This isn't clear to me: "but it doesn't automatically enforce the update until the user clicks on the button in the PR". By "the button" do you mean the "Update branch" button? Could you describe what you wish would happen that isn't currently happening?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific but based on your answer it seems like I would have to use some sort of git commands to achieve what I want. I thought there might be a way for me to just enable some setting on the GitHub UI and it would automatically merge any branch that is out of date with the main branch

Comment: Any merge is error prone, there can be merge conflicts making the merge impossible, but also there are ways a merge might succeed but produce invalid results. Also if there were many changes on the main branch, this would cause a very intransparent history of merges. Hence this feature would likely cause more trouble than benefit.

Comment: So you want that the branch is automatically merged as soon as it is behind, right? I guess there could be a way using a github action. I am not aware of any specific.



Re: "Any merge is error prone"

GH actually only shows this when there are no merge conflicts. Otherwise, the merge needs to be done manually.

Comment: I was looking for this exact feature from GitHub. We have 10 PRs open from team members at any time and when 1 PR gets merged, we suddenly have 9 PRs to update. This feature would automate the tedious process of updating PRs, and the top answer provides a successful solution. (we squash-merge all our PRs to keep linear history)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this action is what you are looking for?
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-update

> autoupdate is a GitHub Action that auto-updates pull requests branches whenever changes land on their destination branch.